# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! in Spring Rest Template

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I am facing a weird issue while calling a REST url using Spring's RestTemplate.I am using Spring Boot.

The error is occurring only after approx **10 to 15 successful calls** and thereafter **erratically**. I can smoothly exchange data before the error, in the first 1 to 15 calls approx. Url is like `someresturl/param1/param2/param3`.

```
     public ResponseEntity<String> callRestUrl(CustomReqClass req) {

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("someresturl");

   finishTaskUrl.append("/").append(param1).append("/").append(param2).append("/").append(param3);        
            ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

            HttpEntity<CustomReqClass> request = new HttpEntity<CustomReqClass>(req, getHTTPHeaders());

       try {

              //first approach
                response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url.toString(), request, String.class, Collections.<String, String>emptyMap());

               //second approach
               response = restTemplate.exchange(url.toString(), HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Error calling url" + e);
            }
            return response;
        }

   public MultiValueMap<String, String> getHTTPHeaders() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic authabcdxyz");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return headers;
}
```

Here I am autowiring restTemplate object in the class where I am using this.
I have tried both the above methods **postForEntity** and **exchange** of Rest template. Error is occurring for both.

The exception I am getting after first few successful attempts:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

As an additional thought, the above piece of code is being scheduled by Spring Scheduler mechanism. Is it possible internal threading used in scheduler is causing this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay, will keep in mind @halfer